# Creating one simple image in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am not sure how to show images from different destinations in Python. I need to know how to make the image show up on my program. I tried using the following code but it would not show the gif file onto the Python program. My file is named "giftest.gif" and it is on the same folder as the program is but it still won't show up, and instead an error pops up.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = Image("giftest.gif")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wait, I think I made a mistake in my program. Perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IW28o11vJfE helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `PhotoImage` not `Image`.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

imagetest = PhotoImage(file="file.gif")
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=imagetest)

root.mainloop()
```